# process null value in join condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table name is `t1`,`t2`.

`t1` record is

```
id           unit       
1            A
2            A
3            A
```

`t2` table record is

```
id            unit
1              A
2              null
3              B
```

so i want result like(if that column has null we dont care about it)

```
id          unit
1           A
2           NULL
```

Comment: what about your id=3? why isnt it in your desired result?

Comment: would you be able to solve it, with the information provided? i guess not

Comment: id in desired result is from t1 or t2?

Comment: can you please give more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM   t1
       INNER JOIN t2
       ON (   t1.id = t2.id
          AND ( t1.unit = t2.unit OR t2.unit IS NULL ) )
```

Comment: `select t1.id, nvl2(t2.unit, t1.unit, null)
    from t1, t2 where t1.id = t2.id and (t1.unit = t2.unit OR t2.unit is null);` should also work I think.

Comment: `AND ( t1.unit = t2.unit OR t2.unit IS NULL ) )` can be rewritten like so: `AND ( t1.unit = nvl(t2.unit, t1.unit)) )`

Comment: @g00dy The `NLV2` in your first query is unnecessary - as per the join condition either `t1.unit = t2.unit` or `t2.unit` is `NULL` so it is the equivalent of `NVL2( t2.unit, t2.unit, t2.unit )` or just `t2.unit`. The second query is potentially less efficient as it adds a function which may prevent the query using indexes.

Answer (score 0):

you could also write it without the AND element, something like this:

```
  SELECT t2.* FROM 

     t1 INNER JOIN  t2 

    ON t1.id = t2.id OR (t1.unit IS NULL AND t2.unit IS NULL)

    ORDER BY t1.unit
```